# applying iqr filter on all columns in R using dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, iqr

filtering data of all columns between their IQRs.
Tried using filter_all(df_name,IQR(.)), returns the same dataframe

Answer (score 3):

`IQR` returns a single value with the distance between the 25th and 75th quantiles. To get all the data that is within this range, it is better to just use the `quantile` function directly. Here is how you can do it with `dplyr::filter`

```
data <- tibble::tibble(x = rnorm(100))

data %>% 
  dplyr::filter(x > quantile(x, 0.25), 
                x < quantile(x, 0.75))
```